# Windows Phone. Record audio stream being played in shout cast media stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-recording, shoutcast

I am trying to record audio being played in windows phone 8 app. I am using **shout cast media stream** I have created the player but stock in recording what is being played. I am completely stocked. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. You can take a look at this code.
[https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DA7EEFF41D054F3B!2923&authkey=!AFb4W8Z78GbZH5I&ithint=folder%2csuo](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DA7EEFF41D054F3B!2923&authkey=!AFb4W8Z78GbZH5I&ithint=folder%2Csuo)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.
You can access the mic but when you'll try to record the playing sound, the sound will stop because of the mic.